# Implement html syntax highlighting when it is the value of a monaco editor with language json

Tags: java, monaco-editor

I am making a project that uses the Monaco editor as its base text editor. If the editor language is JSON, but for one of the fields, the value is HTML, I am wondering if it is possible to have syntax highlighting for the HTML aspect. More specifically, if I have a line in my JSON that reads: `"description": "<p>sample html<p>"` when I double click on 'html' I want 'sample html' to be highlighted, but I am only able to get the word I double click on to be highlighted.

Only the single word I double-click on is highlighted, not everything in the HTML tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot syntax highlight text based on the caret position. The standard highlighter is based on regular expressions and works based on entire lines.